# How to make the cookie authentication middleware redirect to https URIs?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, https

I am using [cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2). For unauthenticated requests, the middleware redirects the browser to a login page. The target URI of the redirect is always using the http scheme, even though the initial request is using HTTPS. I want the redirect to always use HTTPS, but I cannot figure out how to make that work.

Here is what I found so far:

1. It *works* when I run Kestrel locally.
2. It *does not work* on my web host.
3. My web host is using IIS as a reverse proxy for kestrel.
4. Https requests reach the hosted Kestrel as http.
5. The cookie authentication middleware uses the request scheme to build the redirection URI. Because of 4) this always results in a redirect to an http-URI.

How do I resolve this? 
Can I configure IIS to use HTTPS to communicate with Kestrel or can I just somehow force the middleware to output https-URIs?

Comment: have you tried adding the https redirect middleware

Comment: @Neville Yes, I have added that middleware. It makes no difference, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`, you need to specify the `HTTPS Port`.

Turn to `launchSettings.json` and change the `iisSettings.iisExpress.sslPort` to a valid port number like `44371`.

If you fail to launch the project after specifying the port, try to Project Property->Debug->check Enable SSL->Save